# Tweepy api.followers and count limits

Tags: python, twitter, count, tweepy

I'm looking to retrieve the followers on some account with more than 5000 followers.

I've seen in a other topic than it's easier to proceed by page then by items per page. (link : [tweepy count limited to 200?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460560/tweepy-count-limited-to-200))

Once it reads all the id, it must check on the profile description if there is a element of a list i created before.

here's my previous code (note op, without using the api.followers):

```
for element in liste2:
 print element
 resultats = api.search_users(q=element, count=5000)
 for user in resultats:
    print user.id
    i = 0;
    user = api.get_user(user.id)
    print user.name
    while (i != 4):
        if (user.description.find(liste1[i])!= 1):
            print user.name + " valide"
            i = 4;
            statuses = api.user_timeline(id = user.id, count = 20\
```

0)

The counter doesn't work that's why i want to switch for api.followers witch seems to be more nice.

Thanks for reading

Comment: So, you're saying that you just want to get the list of followers of a user who has more than 5K followers, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Also, you have a `0)` that escaped from your code block.